# How to attach VM options for maven command line

Tags: java, spring, maven

how can I add an arguments in maven command line defined as VM option.
In Intellij I have the configuration

```
java 11 -Djasypt.encryptor.password=xxx
```

That solution works perfectly when I am reading VM option using @Value annotation in configuration class.

```
@Value("${jasypt.encryptor.password}")
private String jasyptEncryptorPassword;
```

I am using following command mvn -Djasypt.encryptor.password=xx spring-boot:run
But it failed to fetch with following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jasyptConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jasypt.encryptor.password' in value "${jasypt.encryptor.password}"
```

Only for command java -jar is possible to attach VM options ?

Comment: Please check you spring-boot plugin configuration if it runs in forked mode the maven JVM arguments won't be padded to forked JVM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can attach the VM options to the spring boot plugin as below:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Djasypt.encryptor.password=xxx"
```

check the docs for the plugin here: [spring-boot-maven-plugin docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run)

Other option would be to set it in the `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <jvmArguments>
            -Djasypt.encryptor.password=xxx
        </jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This solution can be also applied for mvn test ?

Comment: No. to set test scoped properties, you can create a test scoped property file with a name application-test.properties. have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tests-override-properties

Comment: How about this -DargLine="-Djasypt.encryptor.password=$1" ?

Comment: for `mvn test`? I don't think it will work.

Comment: mvn verify -P test-docker  -DargLine="-Djasypt.encryptor.password=$1" That solution worked.